# Restricting Menus on a Site Template

Tags: 2013, security, site-template

I have a workflow that creates a site based on a template.  Is there a way to restrict menu options based on a security group?

I have tried Audience Targeting which works fine since I just need to hide the menu options, however, audience targeting doesn't save with the template.

I have tried using read restrictions since most of the links are to lists, the issue is, I need those list items to show on a dashboard page.  If I lock the site down enough where they won't see the list items in the menu, they also can't see anything on the Dashboard for those lists since it's restricted.

Basically I need a template where my Read Only members can only see the Dashboard page which has lists webparts added to it but not the lists themselves.  My contributors need to see all the lists and the dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try OOTB cross-site publishing solution. You need two separate site collections [[MSDN Article]](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635883.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

- Content Authoring Site Collection (Contributors create contents, blocked for visitors) .
- Publishing Site Collection
  (Dashboard for visitors).

[image]

1. Content is created in libraries and lists that are shared as catalogs in the authoring site collection.
2. The search system crawls the content and builds the search index.
3. A user views a page on a publishing site, which triggers queries from Search Web Parts.
4. Results are returned from the search index, and shown in Search Web Parts on the page.

Comment: Thanks Asim, sorry for the delay on the answer. I tweaked it a bit but used your idea.  Since I already had a bunch of sites I just created a bunch of pages using content search webpart to create the dashboards.